# power bi DAX catch values in tables

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-custom-visuals

i have 2 tables:
[image]

I would like to see how many values table one exists in table two and how many aren't exist in table tow
so the result should be for example 5 exit and 10 not exist

Comment: Please try to describe your problem clearly with examples of underlying data, expected and actual results. Right now, I really don't understand the problem.

Comment: sorry, I re-wrote the post. I hope it will help!

Comment: You can Join tables using the key column. Then you can count all rows with Value and NULL to get your expected output.

Comment: is there another way like using DAX:

Number of Table2 rows =
CALCULATE(
    COUNTROWS(Table2),
    FILTER(
        Table2,
        Table2[Column1] = Table1[Column1]
    )
)